# Process Builder & Custom Metadata Types - Issue with Long Text Area

Tags: process-builder, custom-metadata

I want to create a Process Builder that updates a Long Text Area field with a Long Text Area field value from a Custom Metadata Type.

When I'm selecting the Custom Metadata Type in the Process Builder action `(Global System Variable > $CustomMetadata > Sample Metadata Type > Sample Record 1)` I'm able to select a variety of fields such as standard fields or custom fields I created. Unfortunately I'm unable to access custom Long Text Area fields of the Custom Metadata Type record. The target field has the same length as the source field of the Custom Metadata Type.

Is this a known restriction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked on this feature.

Unfortunately long text area fields are not supported in formula references to custom metadata types. The reason is related to the way we cache LTA values. (It's the same reason that [SOQL queries that include LTA fields are counted differently too](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custommetadatatypes_limits.htm&type=5).)

Thanks for calling this out. We're going to update the documentation to make this clearer.

Comment: Thank you, Carolyn!